# Pass render props to children in a React complement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

I have a component, called `Pagination` and I want to pass multiple props down to the children of the component, similar to `active` on the Menu item of Headless UI’s menu:

```
<Menu.Item>
  {({ active }) => (
    <a className={`${active && 'bg-blue-500'}`} href="/account-settings">
      Account settings
    </a>
  )}
</Menu.Item>
```

I want to pass an `activeItem` prop and `itemsCount` prop, and allow users to render it in whatever way they want to. An example implementation could be:

```
<Pagination>
  {({ activeItem, itemsCount }) => (
    <span>{ activeItem }</span>
    <span>{ itemCount }</span>
  )}
</Pagination>
```

And the baseline component for Pagination is:

```
interface PaginationProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
  children: React.ReactElement;
}

const Pagination = ({ children, ...rest }: PaginationProps) => {
  const { state } = useLightboxContext();
  return (
    <div {...rest}>
    </div>
  );
};
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can render it as `props.children({ activeItem: ..., itemsCount: ... })` in the component, and the user will pass in `{({ activeItem, itemsCount }) => ...}` as the child.

Comment: So no `createElement` or anything similar? Just pass it in via the `children` prop?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment, here is the way to do it:

```
function Comp({ children }) {
  return children({ activeItem: 1, itemsCount: 2 });
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Comp>
      {({ activeItem, itemsCount }) => (
        <p>
          {activeItem}, {itemsCount}
        </p>
      )}
    </Comp>
  );
}
```

This will render `1, 2`.

Comment: Thanks; added more to my question to give better clarity, but this is erroring out in Typescript; any tips before I work through it?